# With sendmany, how to specify the "subtractfeefrom" so that I pay the fee, but it's not subtracted from any of the "inner transactions"?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc

https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/wallet/sendmany/

If I don't want the recipient to pay the fee, but I also don't want to subtract the fee from any of the "inner transactions" specified (that is, I want to pay it myself), what do I do with the "subtractfeefrom" parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:

> The fee will be equally deducted from the amount of each selected
> address.
>
> Those recipients will receive less bitcoins than you enter in their
> corresponding amount field.
>
> **If no addresses are specified here, the sender pays the fee.**

So it seems like you simply don't specify any addresses in that field.

Comment: I seriously read "If no addresses are specified here, the recipient pays the fee." ... Several times. I don't get how that is possible, but it's true. Hmm.